# Supervisor ulimits

Tags: linux, process, supervisord, ulimit

- I wanted to know how to modify the ulimits of supervisor process particularly.
- I want increase max open process limit to unlimited for supervisor process so that , it will spawn it's child process with the same ulimits.

See the below screen shots for more info:

**The below is the ulimit of the root user after changing it in /etc/security/limits.conf**

[image]

**The below is the ulimit of the supervisor process.**

[image]

Now , i want to know how to make them same .

Answer (score 0):

you can set the [supervisord] `minfds` and `minprocs` in config file